# CollapsingToolbarLayout causes RecyclerView's bottom to be underscreen

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have AppBarLayout with fixed height (@dimen/app_bar_height = 200dp), which has CollapsingToolbarLayout in it. When scrolling down, part of recyclerview is hidden under screen bottom.

If I remove scroll flags (ie. disable scrolling collapse) I remove `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"` from CollapsingToolbarLayout then it is normally aligning screen bottom.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <!-- Problem HERE in app:layout_scrollFlags -->
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:expandedTitleGravity="bottom"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap" 
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

            <TextView
                android:text="Hello, Hello, Hello, Hello, Hello, Hello, Hello, Hello, Hello, Hello"
                android:textSize="19sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:id="@+id/txtDescr"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.5"/>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/detail_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

            <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fab"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|start"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/stat_notify_chat" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:scrollbarSize="7dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Try removing snap from app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"

Comment: @ParagPawar Thanks, but same. Only `scroll` if removed it is fixed, but disabling scroll

Comment: Can you try setting height of the AppBarLayout to wrap_content and see if that works?

Comment: `wrap_content` 1) hides fab in app bar 2) still bottom of recyclerview is hidden

Comment: i have a doubt... @FindOutIslamNow ...when you scroll recycleview the collapsing toolbar still present ? recycleview going under collapsing toolbar? can you share screenshot of what you are getting and what exactly you need ?

Comment: @FindOutIslamNow  i added my answer...if my solution doesnt match as per your requirement let me know

Comment: @Wini Thanks, but what I have is that recyclerview is going under screen. Its bottom is hidden underscreen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the followiing, to detect last item scroll and notifyDataSetChanged(), that solves the issue :

```
    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

        private boolean hasFixedLastItemNotVisible = false;

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

            if (!hasFixedLastItemNotVisible &&
                    !recyclerView.canScrollVertically(10) &&
                    newState==RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                hasFixedLastItemNotVisible = true;
                recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Tried your code multiple times with no luck. Finally found a workaround. Just add the height of view which you want to pin at the top as margin-bottom to the recyclerView keeping recyclerView's height as wrap_content.

For Ex. If you want to pin your toolbar then add it's height as margin-bottom to the recycler view

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:scrollbarSize="7dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your time with me. But there is a small problem: the margin bottom fixed value will not be suitable after the collapse (e.g if you set its value to equal app_bar_height, what if I collapse?)

Comment: You're not going to collapse everything right? You're pinning the Toolbar, so it will always be visible. If you're not pinning anything then you don't need to set margin, It will show your last item.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Please check yourself. I need to solve the issue using the current UI.

Comment: Remove this app:layout_collapseMode="pin" from toolbar and fab, then all will be collapsed, and you'll see the last item of your recyclerview

Comment: And if you want to keep the toolbar and fab pinned at the top, then whatever height is of those elements give it as the bottom margin to the recyclerView.

Comment: I've created a demo to test this, you can download it and check:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eamuiKGMLOGjfRzzpQeeEpSEcy-nlM43/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Also, if you'd notice in the demo I've not used android:fitsSystemWindows="true" for any view group, so might want to remove that as well.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you are loading the items in the RecyclerView too soon, before the CoordinatorLayout has finished measuring the AppbarLayout. This may happen if you have your list of items immediately available in your `onViewCreated` and you create and assign your adapter right away.
I don't know how you setup your RecyclerView in your code, but I had this same problem and I solved it by using `View.post(Runnable)`:

```kotlin
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    val adapter = MyAdapter(viewModel.items)
    // replace:
    // recyclerView.adapter = adapter
    // with:
    view.post { recyclerView.adapter = adapter }
}
```

Also note that if you happened to use a subclass of [ListAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ListAdapter), which works asynchronously from the main thread, infact you would likely not have had this issue.

Comment: `onViewCreated` what do you mean? I am creating adapter at the parent fragment `onCreateView` using a background thread then `activity.runOnUiThread(() -> ` to create adapter and assign to recyclerview (which is the same of post)

Comment: I had this problem with a RecyclerView inside a Fragment, I were simply creating and assigning the adapter in the Fragment's `onViewCreated`. If your setup is more complex, share some code if you can, so we can have some clues.

Answer (score 0):

when scrolling down recycleview....if you dont want a toolbar as recycleview is getting hidden behind toolbar....

use this--> `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed"`

so your collapsingtoolbarlayout code will be-->

```
 <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        >
```

Comment: if my solution doesnt worked i suggest you put your screenshots above...what you are getting and what you want ?two images

Comment: I want to pin toolbar after collapse.

Comment: First tell me I didn't understand this statement `it's bottom is hidden under screeN` what do you mean by bottom?

Comment: Screen bottom. After you scroll, the toobar is collapsed and recyclerview expanded. But the last item (bottom) in recyclerview is 50% visible and 50% hidden underscreen